# horizontally shrink text in CrystalReports

Tags: fonts, crystal-reports, fontforge

I have following problem.
I'm recreating an A3-sized label in **CrystalReports**, and there is a text field which has to be Arial 115, bold, 0.5 usual width.

One can do it in HTML by using `transform:scaleX(0.5)`.

```html
<p style="font-family: 'Arial'; font-weight:bold; font-size: 115px;transform:scaleX(0.5);">SOME LONGER TEXT (scaled down)</p>

<p style="font-family: 'Arial'; font-weight:bold; font-size: 115px;">SOME LONGER TEXT (no scaling)</p>
```

And although CrystalReports has some understanding of HTML, it doesn't support the `transform`s.

So I'm asking if there is any way.
This report is part of a .net-program, is there maybe some API-function for this?

I thought about generating and installing the shrunk down fonts I need (there will be 6 of them), but I couldn't find out how.

**UPDATE** I've posted my solution below.

Comment: What output are you ending up with, do you need to export to PDF or HTML or just print?

Comment: @bendataclear I need to just print it (and there is a PDF printer, so this isn't a problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing:

1. get the font file (in my case: C:\Windows\Fonts\arialbd.ttf);
2. open it in [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/) ("About" says it's the version from 31.07.2017);
3. change it's name (Element - Font Info - PS Names). I ended up with Fontname: `ArialShrunk-050-BoldMT`, Family Name: `Arial Shrunk 050`, Name For Humans: `Arial Shrunk 050 Bold`; when asked about changing unique id press "Change";
4. change or remove translated font names (Element - Font Info - TTF Names), else it won't be installed (because windows checks localized font names for some reason). I removed every line which wasn't "English (US)".
5. save as .sfd;
6. Edit - Select - Glyphs Worth Outputting;
7. Element - Transformations - Transform;
8. set *Origin* to `Glyph Origin`; first action to `Scale`, *X* to `50` (leave *Y* at `100`);
   *Transform All Layers*, *Transform Guide Layer Too*, *Round To Int* unchecked;
   *Transform Width Too*, *Transform kerning classes too*, *Transform simple positioning features & kern pairs* checked;
   [image: set up FontForge "Transform"-window]
9. press OK and wait a little;
10. File - Generate Fonts, ensure `TrueType` is selected, uncheck `Validate Before Saving` (saves a click); press *Generate*, press *OK* in the "Lookup potentially too big"-Warning;
11. Find the newly generated ArialShrunk-050-BoldMT.ttf file, double-click it, press *Install* to install the font.

Now there is a new system-wide font `Arial Shrunk 050` for me to use everywhere, especially in CrystalReports.

It's not quite ideal, but since there is not too many scaling variations I need to generate, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using HTML as an intermediary, I've not tested this as it's a little complex so might take some debugging to get working.

First add a `cssClass` value to the text object in the Crystal document (in the properties). Something like `shrinkobject`.

Next export the crystal report to html text.

Then inject the html text with a style tag like:

```
html = html.Replace("<HTML>", "<HTML><style>p.shrinkObject {transform:scaleX(0.5);}</style>");
```

This html should then apply the CSS value and can be rendered to the printer.

Comment: I have a question about the "Next export the crystal report to html text": this should happen at run time, right? I would then have yet another problem: how do I actually render the modified HTML before sending it to printer (the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser from .NET-Framework doesn't support it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UFL (User Function Library) to compute the largest font size that would fit the text within a given boundary area. Create your own or see list of 3rd-party UFL's [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl).

Here is a [description of GetFontSizeToFitText()](https://milletsoftware.com/CUT_Light_User_Manual/#uflGetFontSizeToFitText()) function in my UFL.

Comment: is it possible to scale font only horizontally without changing the size with Your software?

Comment: Please clarify: do you mean keep font height the same but reduce width as if you are resizing an image? For that you would need to use 2 other functions:
HTML2Image() allows you to convert HTML text to an image. 
ImageResize() allows you to resize an image
and you can use the 'Graphic Location' expression for a dummy image to load and replace the dummy image with the resulting resized image. 

But it seems simpler and better to replace the original font size with the font size that would fit the content in the available space.

Comment: I do want to keep the same height; and while it's simpler to change the font size, it's not better: I would need to change it from 115 to about 60 to fit horizontally, which leaves a **huge** gap vertically. The HTML2Image && ImageResize (or even the 1st one alone if it understands the `transform`) is ok, but I'd like to avoid having too many images on a report if possible (I assume it negatively affects printing).